# Using FART (Find and replace text) unable to replace text

Tags: batch-file, find-and-replace

My goal:
replace a string in a JSON file, using FART **or any method that works** While having it be run via a Batch file

The code I have is:

```
fart.exe launcher_profiles.json "1.1.2-DXF.12.2-14.23.5.2768" [SOMETHING ELSE]
```

It's not finding or actually replacing anything in the file.
The text I need to replace MUST include `" "` 's

-→ Error:
[image]

> Q: Yes FART is in the dir // correct dir with the file
>
> Q: FART seems to replace other things, but not this, and the documentation is a bit shotty, and I'm a bit unfamiliar with it

Not opposed to using other things, but FART was recommended, so I tried to use that, and I'm running into a few issues

Comment: I assume you are using Windows from the `*.exe` extension on the utility you have chosen. You can do this with `powershell` without having to install additional utilities: https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-replace-text-in-file/ If you're on macos/unix/linux, use `sed` for this